# Improve performance on simple query with table of 10 million rows

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

Consider there is a big table called.... `BigTable` with 10 million rows. Originally, there is no primary key so I added identity column along with primary key constraint and clustered index.

```
ALTER TABLE BigTable ADD id int identity(1,1) not null;
ALTER TABLE BigTable ADD CONSTRAINT pk_id primary key CLUSTERED (id);
```

Then I did a simple select

```
select id from BigTable;
```

SQL server took `1 mins 23 seconds` return the result.

```
set statistics time on
 SQL Server Execution Times:
 CPU time = 10063 ms,  elapsed time = 65740 ms.

execution plan just simply showed a "Clustered Index scan" with cost of 100%
Number of Rows Read      10332000
Estimated Operator Cost  1740.89(100%)
Estimated I/O Cost       1729.52
Estimated Cpu Cost       11.3654
Estimated SubTree Cost   1740.89
Number of Executions     1
```

The reason I used this simple query is because I really try to rule out the performance factor from the query, and then still try to figure out: how to get this simple query return result in less than a couple second? Is it really the max performance I can get from SQL server to query on 10 million rows?

Comment: The time is probably taken just physically transferring the data. You're *not* filtering or ordering, so indexes aren't going to help anyway. What does the execution plan show you?

Comment: Indexes, surrogate key etc. are performance optimisations that try to solve specific performance problems (usually at a cost of something else - upsert performance, and more disk space). Simply creating an index does not magically make everything faster. What is your problem?

Comment: @Dale K thanks execution plan just simply showed a "Clustered Index scan" with cost of 100%, I have added some details in the OP

Comment: @Alex Thanks I tried to see if SQL server can actually run any query that can be blazing fast (finished in a couple second) across 10 million rows without limitation on scanning (i.e. no Top or limit ). Just simply can `select some_fields where condition` return results in a couple seconds across the 10 million rows if optimize indexing properly

Comment: @Dreamer "Run the query" is different to "Return the results". SQL Server doesn't in itself have any say over how long it will take to display that many results to you. Returning 10M results is always going to take some time... and probably isn't what you are actually wanting to test. Filtering out a sub-set of rows to return is probably of more interest.

Comment: @DaleK ah I see. Is there any physical evidence can tell the difference between `query run time` and `Return the results` time from execution plan? I have updated the OP, is `cpu time/cost` means `query run time` and `elapsed time ` or `I/O cost` means the "returning result time"?

Comment: I/O cost means reading from the disk. The data has to be loaded into memory before SQL Server can do anything with it. Thats where Davids answer suggests a performance improvement, if you just have a non-clustered index on `id` SQL Server can load a lot less information into memory.

Comment: Google "sql server set statistics" - probably "set statistics time"

Comment: @Dale K Well then in SQL server how to find out the actually time from "Run the query" and "Return the results" in a query run respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scan all the values of *any* column from a clustered index requires a complete table scan.  If you want to optimize for retrieving all the `id`s or count the rows try a non-clustered index on `id` or a columnstore index.

Comment: Thank you David. So basically if join tables by foreign key / primary key between two huge tables, it is better to use non-clustered index or columnstore index?

Comment: @Dreamer the answer, as always with SQL Server, is it depends. If you are joining the table on, one assumes you want to access other columns from the table. Which columns and how many columns will determine what indexes you need. Performance tuning is not as simple as following a few rules, it a very complex topic, and unique to each system.

Comment: Moreover, arbitrary test queries do not usually give you any useful information to apply to your actual live queries.